# Best practice for node - mongo - angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I have an app I am designing using node/mongo/angular, what I am not getting is how is the best way to get my data from mongo into my pages? I can use node, and thru my routes send back data from mongo with my template(hogan in this case), and bind using mustachejs. That works fine for most things. I have one screen that has a decent amount of drop down lists, to bind them for an edit scenario now seems a challenge. I would like to get them bound to an angular model and go about it that way. Is it better to get the data thru the route in node, then use something like ng-init and get it into angular? Or would I be better off not getting the data thru the route in node, and then using angular to perform a "get" request and bind that way?

Comment: In your second option you will perform a get request to what?

Comment: I need to load data on the page, right now, I can write a route, and pass my data in and have it rendered with my template. My problem is how to set drop down list boxes in an edit scenario strictly doing things this way. I have done some angular stuff where I use that to bind my form items, doing drop down list boxes and setting up and edit scenario is much easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation of `ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit), more precisely from the red warning alert at the top of the page...:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So no, do not use ng-init. While that can be a good strategy for lazy migrations from regular applications to single page applications, it's a bad idea from an architectural point of view.

Most importantly, you lose two things:

1. An API. The benefit of SPAs is that you have an API and that you're constantly developing and maintaining it, even before it has external users
2. A clean separation of concerns. Views are strictly limited to presentation, can be cached by the client and all data is transferred through JSON API endpoints.

Comment: Thanks, I was not intending for this to be a spa app per se, but will look at this and rethink my approach.

Comment: Well, making a non-single-page application with angular is possible, but it's kind of mind-bending. Helpful for migrations or to avoid a jquery slashfest, but if you start from scratch I'd suggest you do SPA w/ angular or use something like twitter flight instead.

Comment: Thanks, the spa/angular way is probably how i will go. That should not be too bad for this, its an app that mostly collects data as it goes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best way to get data from Mongo into your page, is as mnemosyn said, using an API.

Basicly, you can have your API route, f.ex '/api/data' configured and then it can be used by a angular service, (which can use ngResource to make things easier). Any controller that wishes to access this data can use the angular service to get it, do some stuff with it, and then update it using the same angular service.